# Add/Insert entity with inherited nested object graph (one to many relationship)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, one-to-many, dbcontext

Adding an entity with 1 level of one to many relationship is pretty straight forward.

```
using (var dbCtx = new DbContext())
{
    dbCtx.Stuff.Add(myObject);
    dbCtx.SaveChanges();
}
```

But how do you add an object with 2 levels? Adding it in the same way omits the 2. level. Which means that the Bar objects (in the example below) isn't saved. What am I doing wrong?

### Object graph

**Inherited objects**

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id;
    // Omitted properites...
}

public class MyEntity : BaseEntity
{
    // Omitted properites...

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

**Nested objects** (1:M)

```
public class Foo // 1. level
{
    public int Id;
    public int MyEntityId;

    // Omitted properites...

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public virutal MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
}

public class Bar // 2. level
{
    public int Id;
    public int FooId;

    // Omitted properites...

    // Navigation properties
    public virutal Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

### Mapping setup using fluent API

**Inherited objects**

```
public class BaseEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity>
{
    public BaseEntityMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BaseEntitySet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityMap()
    {
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BaseEntitySet_MyEntities");
    }
}
```

**Nested objects** (1:M)

```
public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("FooSet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.MyEntityId).HasColumnName("MyEntity_Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.MyEntity)
            .WithMany(t => t.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MyEntityId);
    }
}

public class BarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BarSet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.FooId).HasColumnName("Bar_Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Foo)
            .WithMany(t => t.Bars)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.FooId);
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
public void Add(BaseEntity item)
{
    using (var ctx = new DbContext())
    {
        ctx.BaseEntities.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of the blue it started working...

Comment: Not sure if I should leave it for others to see or delete

Comment: Seeing this same thing right now. Ever find more information on it? The only thing that's working for me is to let the integer ID in the leaf entity ("Bar" in your code) be nullable, and initialize that value to null. Letting be the default 0 throws DBUpdateException.

Answer (score 0):

\Wanted to post my answer in case it helps others, and so the experts can tear it to pieces and post the real answer. For me it did not start working out of the blue :)

If I understand your object graph correctly, it's MyEntity has Foos which has Bars. I had a similar structure, but when calling "SaveChanges" a DbUpdateException would be thrown with a message that

> "multiple entities may have the same primary key."

Here's how I made it work for me:

**Step 1:** Change the Id properties from int to int? and initialize them to null. To me this is a more accurate model than a plain integer. When an entity is new, the ID is literally "undefined or unknown". 0 is a defined number and for some reason EF has a problem with the ID's being the same, even when the records are being added.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        this.Id = null;
    }

    public int? Id;
    // Omitted properites...
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.Id = null;
    }

    public int? Id;
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        this.Id = null;
    }

    public int? Id;
}
```

**Step 2:** Add the "DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity" flag to the Id properties in the mapping. I believe this prevents it from being "required" in the case the entity is added to the datacontext.

```
public class BaseEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity>
{
    public BaseEntityMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BaseEntitySet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        // ...
    }
}

public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("FooSet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.MyEntityId).HasColumnName("MyEntity_Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.MyEntity)
            .WithMany(t => t.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MyEntityId);
    }
}

public class BarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BarSet");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.FooId).HasColumnName("Bar_Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Foo)
            .WithMany(t => t.Bars)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.FooId);
    }
}
```